# Do we say "candy juice" to mean the sticky liquid that comes from a candy?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Do we say "**candy juice**" to mean the sticky liquid that comes from a candy?

Or maybe, "**candy syrup**".

Someone told me "**candy residue**".

Comment: You can say all of those things.

Comment: *Candy juice* is humorous slang.

Comment: "Candy" is mainly used in America to mean "sugar-based confectionery". In other English-speaking areas, "candy juice" might not be understood.

Answer (score 3):

It depends what kind of candy you're talking about. When you say "comes *from* a candy" that can be ambiguous: do you mean a purely hard candy that has melted, or a candy "shell" that contains liquid inside it?

#### Purely hard candy

Example: [Jolly Ranchers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jolly_Rancher), [Gobstoppers/Jawbreakers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gobstopper)

**Candy juice** is not idiomatic at all. "Juice" is a liquid that you get by crushing a fruit or vegetable that already has significant amounts of liquid (or at least moisture) in it.

**Candy syrup** also doesn't really make sense for hard candy. The *syrup* is the viscous "pre-candy" state—hot water and sugar boiled together for a time. The syrup is placed into molds and cooled to form candy.

**Candy residue** would make the most sense when talking about a hard candy that has become a little melted or sticky, especially if you're talking about a smaller amount of material that has become stuck on, or dripped on, something: clothing, face, fingers, countertop, etc.

#### Hard or soft shell with soft filling

Example: [Fruit Gushers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fruit_Gushers) (syrup-filled), [Mon Chéri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mon_Ch%C3%A9ri) (liqueur-filled)

**Candy juice** is actually a good analogy for what is inside the candy but it's not super idiomatic. "Juice" is a term usually used for plants and sometimes animals—in any case usually living or once-living things. As FelinusRex said, it might be used as a joking term, similar to "car juice" for gasoline or engine oil.

**Candy syrup** is precisely what is inside the candy. It is a syrupy sugary liquid that has not hardened.

**Candy residue** is not the right term, unless (as above) you are talking about some amount that is no longer attached to the main piece of candy.

Comment: It's a hard candy with no filling. So, "Candy residue" is correct